# How to fix 'Color' has no member error in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, swiftui

I'm experiencing '`Color' has no member` in SwiftUI, when trying to call the newly created color (color is declared in the Assets).

The strange thing is that I still can call previously created colors. But suddenly I can't call the newly created colors and constanly seeing '`Color' has no member` error for the new colors.

Does anyone have the same problem or know how to fix this?

Already tried to clean, and to reload Xcode.
Seeing this in 11.2.1 (11B500)

Comment: Please copy and paste the relevant code into your question. Don't put code into screenshots as it makes it harder to read and impossible to search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a named color you need to pass the name as a string:

```
Color("colorWhite20")
```

## Extension

You can create a simple extension for `Color` for easier access:

```
extension Color {
    static var colorWhite20 = Color("colorWhite20")
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
Color.colorWhite20
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
.background(Color("colorWhite20"))
```